# Centering Table View in Xcode for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm running Xcode 6 and the tableview I have now runs fine in the iPhone 5 simulator but not the iPhone 6 or 6 plus.  I have checked both "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes."

How do I get the table view to center and have the correct height according to the device size?

[image]

Comment: This is also running iOS SDK 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get ride off the current constrains that you may have (we need to start clean).

For this, select the Table View and then select the |-triangle-| on the bottom of the screen, and select  Clear Constrains.

[image: delete constrains]

### How to define the constrains

You need to select Table View and then go to |-square-| on the bottom of the screen and put 0,0,0,0 (this makes 0 margin to up, bottom, left and right). Press add 4 Constrains (make sure that the four lines are in red)

[image: set constrains]

Now select the Table View again and go to |-triangle-| and put Update Frames. This way you are going to update the Storyboard to see the same that you are going to see when running the App.

#### Deleting extra side margins

We would have a small margin to the sides. So we need to get ride of this. In the left panel select the First Horizontal and then in First Item select Relative to Margin.

[image: delete left margin]

Do this same thing for the second Horizontal on the left panel.

[image: delete right margin]

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked wonders! May I ask where you learned tricks such as this?

Comment: @Nykholas I'm trying to make this work but it doesn't. You say "First Item" but in the screen shot you choose "Second Item" for both.. Which one is it? Thanks.

Comment: @Ali- Just uncheck constrain to margins and you are done.